# ruby, create types for DSL without polluting global namespace

Tags: ruby, types, dsl

I have a DSL that uses custom types (objects that inherit from primitives, i.e. `String`), but I don't want to pollute the global namespace with them because they're only used in a few places and no where else.

If I try to wrap the Types in the same module namespace as the DSL execution context, I get a `NameError`, `uninitialized constant`. I've also tried including the module that wraps the types and even used refinements to the `Object` class but nothing works.

Due to the (relatively) complex nature of the problem I'm not sure if this is what you will need to help me, so I'm guessing.

```
module Forms
  class Define
    class << self
      attr_accessor :forms
      def draw name, &script
        @forms[name] = new(&script)
      end
    end

    def initialize &description
      @meta = {}
      @section_counter = 0
      self.tree = Tree.new
      instance_eval &description
    end
  end
end
```

And used like this:

```
Forms::Define.draw 'Register' do
  #some dsl code...
end
```

EDIT: thanks, didn't notice the typo's, any way.

Since people don't seem to understand "I have a DSL that uses custom types" and "I don't want to pollute the global namespace with them" I'm going to illustrate the problem more specifically.

I'm saying I have types like this:

```
class Some_Custom_Type < String
end
```

But doing it like this, pollutes the global namespace, so if I namespace the type like this:

```
module Forms
  class Some_Custom_Type < String
  end
end
```

and then try to use it:

```
Forms::Define.draw 'Register' do
  some_code_using Some_Custom_Type
  #some dsl code...
end
```

it will error `uninitialized constant Some_Custom_Type (NameError)`

So I ask again with a bit more clarity, how do I ensure `Some_Custom_Type` will be available given the execution context of the DSL without polluting the global namespace?

Comment: I think more information is needed to solve your problem.  Maybe you can submit a link to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an interface.

Given from the example in the OP:

```
module Forms
  module Types
    class Some_Custom_Type < String
    end
  end
end
```

I added:

```
module Forms
  module Types_Wrapper
    def some_custom_type
      Some_Custom_Type
    end
  end

  def self.included(child)
    child.include Types_Wrapper
  end
end
```

Is added like this:

```
module Forms
  class Define
    include Types
  end
end
```

and can be used like this:

```
Forms::Define.draw 'Register' do
  some_code_using some_custom_type
  #some dsl code...
end
```

over:

```
Forms::Define.draw 'Register' do
  some_code_using Some_Custom_Type
  #some dsl code...
end
```

Difference is slight but now works and more DSL like I feel.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood the question properly, but probably something like that would help:

```
@forms[name] = const_set(
  name, 
  Class.new(Object) do |c|
    c.send :define_method, :initialize, *args, &script
  end
)
```

After call to `Forms::Define.draw 'Register'` you will have a class `Forms::Define::Register`, available from anywhere.